# Why Laravel does not recognize recently added records in a table

Tags: laravel

I am doing following 3 steps:

1. Inserting records from Master table to Temp table
2. Displaying Temp table in Data table
3. Editing records in Data table and updating Mem table.

So, Step 1 no issue,  I am able to insert records in Temp table using Model::Create command.
Step 2 no issue,  I am able to bring these records to Data table as well and can see these newly inserted records in temp table in MySQL as well.

Issue is with step 3. When I click the edit button on data table, It gives an error
"message": "Attempt to read property "PMDTDUniqueId" on null",
So it is not recognizing the newly inserted records even when I can see it in enter code hereMySQL and Data table.

Why it should behave like this?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
// Inserting Records from Master table to Temp Table

public function PMDTH11AppendMemTableTrait()
{        
    $loginName = Auth::user()->name;
    // Delete Records for this user first 
    MemIncomeType::where('PMDTDUser', $loginName)->delete();
    $Master = IncomeType::orderBy('PMITHUniqueId')->get();
    $LineNo = 10;
    foreach ($Master as $key => $value) {
        MemIncomeType::create([
            'PMDTDUniqueIdH'    => $LineNo,
            'PMDTDIncomeId'     => $value->PMITHIncomeId,
            'PMDTDIncomeIdK'    => $value->PMITHIncomeIdK,
            'PMDTDDesc1'        => $value->PMITHDesc1,
            'PMDTDIsSelect'     => 0,
            'PMDTDDedPercent'   => 100,
            'PMDTDUser'         => $loginName                
        ]);
        $LineNo++;
    }
}
```

// Editing Record that are newly inserted as above

```
public function PMDTH11FethchEditedSubFormDataTrait($request)
{
    $PMDTDUniqueId = $request->input('id');        
    $MemIncomeType = MemIncomeType::find($PMDTDUniqueId);
    // $MemIncomeType = MemIncomeType::where('PMDTDUniqueId', $PMDTDUniqueId)->get();
    // echo 'Data Submitted.';
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($MemIncomeType);
    // die();
    return $output = array(
        'PMDTDUniqueId'     =>  $MemIncomeType->PMDTDUniqueId,
        'PMDTDIncomeId'     =>  $MemIncomeType->PMDTDIncomeId,
        'PMDTDDesc1'        =>  $MemIncomeType->PMDTDDesc1,
        'PMDTDDedPercent'   =>  $MemIncomeType->PMDTDDedPercent
    );
}
```

In the above function 'PMDTH11FethchEditedSubFormDataTrait' I am getting the error.

The model I declared for MemIncomeType

```
namespace App\Models\Payroll\IncomeDeductionType;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MemIncomeType extends Model
{
use HasFactory;    
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'zmem11906l0211';
protected $primaryKey = 'PMDTDUniqueId';
protected $fillable = 
    [
        'PMDTDUniqueId',
        'PMDTDUniqueIdH',
        'PMDTDIncomeId', 
        'PMDTDIncomeIdK',
        'PMDTDDesc1',
        'PMDTDIsSelect',
        'PMDTDDedPercent',
        'PMDTDUser',
    ];
}
```

Comment: When using find() it uses your primary key as defined in your database migration, can you post this? 

Might it be possible that this is not your Primary Key?

Comment: "Eloquent will also assume that each model's corresponding database table has a primary key column named id. If necessary, you may define a protected $primaryKey property on your model to specify a different column that serves as your model's primary key." - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys

Comment: I have even posted the Model for MemIncomeType.
The funny part is: When I execute this program and on click event it appends the records and show in DB as well in Datatable but doesnt allow me to edit any of the record since It is not finding records in this table.
But if I comment this mem table creation function on click event and execute the same program, Now the same code above is allowing me to edit these records. To me the function AppendMemTable is inserting the records in DB but internally Laravel is not recognizing this insert.

Comment: @Danny Ebbers
 if you look into the function 'PMDTH11FethchEditedSubFormDataTrait' and specifically third line that is commented. I tried to pick the records using where clause instead of find. But that also brought null records to me. I checked it using this small way of debugging that are commented in 4-7 lines.
I hope this clarify your doubt about Find. I know Find works only with id. We have explicitly declared our id key in model as 'protected $primaryKey = 'PMDTDUniqueId';'.

Comment: Try `MemIncomeType::findOrFail()` and watch for the exception. Check your database query logs to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks @miken32. Tried this and got the following error message
 "message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Payroll\\IncomeDeductionType\\MemIncomeType] 853",

Comment: One more twist I tried @miken32.
I kept one record in MemIncomeType in a way that it will not get deleted by function 'PMDTH11AppendMemTableTrait' because of where condition.
Now after executing this program, I do have an old record that I kept purposely and newly inserted records from function 'PMDTH11AppendMemTableTrait'.
I am able to edit the old retained record with the same function 'PMDTH11FethchEditedSubFormDataTrait', but getting the errors for newly inserted records.
Cant understand why?

Comment: Sorry guys, still an issue.
After changing posting type POST, I did not check the error message since It allowed me to edit. But after review error message, it said CSRF-Token mismatches. Since it was mismatched, the function 'PMDTH11AppendMemTableTrait' failed. Hence MemIncomeTable was having old data and edit was possible on old data.
But when I added csrf-token in my ajax call, the function 'PMDTH11AppendMemTableTrait' started working and inserted new records in MemIncomeType. Now I am unable to edit these newly inserted records.
So back to square.

Comment: Do I need to refresh() the model after creating records using PMDTH11AppendMemTableTrait. If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: The Issue is resolved finally. It was logical issue. I was loading Datatable first followed by click event to insert new records. It should be other way round.
Sorry for all the mess created by me.